# Faster way to copy rows of data to different sheets by column value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find a faster way to copy specific rows of a sheet to different sheets. Iterating through them as done in code below takes too much time it leads to timeout.

Some information about origin sheet:

1. Has already a blocked header
2. Has around 5000 rows
3. Column A has a header "Project"
4. Sheet is sorted by Column A

Goal is to copy range of all rows for each project from origin sheet to a blank sheet that is named from specific project - so all rows that has in column e.g. "ProjectA" in column A are in a sheet called "ProjectA".

Here is a code that is working, but it is using very slow iteration, so I'm waiting around 20 minutes or even get a timeout when I'm processing it:

```
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var columnRoom = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
    var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
    var header = rows[0];
    var completedRooms = []
    var last = columnRoom[1][0]
    for (var i = 1; i < columnRoom.length; i++) {
        if (!completedRooms.includes(columnRoom[i][0])) {
            if (columnRoom[i][0] === "") {
                var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet("No Room");
            } else {
                var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(columnRoom[i][0]);
            }
            currentSheet.appendRow(header);
            currentSheet.appendRow(rows[i]);
            completedRooms.push(columnRoom[i][0])
            last = columnRoom[i][0]
        } else if (last == columnRoom[i][0]) {
            var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
            currentSheet.appendRow(rows[i]);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to do it faster? I'm thinking about appending specific rows to a range and use copyTo but I can't arrange it, maybe use map function?

Comment: `forEach()` is faster than the conventional `for` loop, and yes - `map()` is even faster. Here is a [useful article](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/3331e1e631d619abef8f32c4be14ba3a) by Tanaike.

Comment: I don't think the main issue in this code is the `for` loop rather than the `appendRow()` the OP is iteratively using.

Comment: I believe you should put this code to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since there are a lot of improvements that makes this a whole new project rather than minor fixes. Since you are creating sheets on the fly, you should create a json array and use as keys the sheet objects and as values an array of the elements you want to append. In this way, you will fill in this json array and then use it to `setValues()` in every sheet and you will get rid of all the `appendRows()`s you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The number of times you call `insertSheet()` and `appendRow()` functions is what makes your script slow.

For the `appendRow()` problem, instead of calling this function multiple times, send your data in a single call. For example, on lines 14-15 instead of calling `appendRow(header)` + `appendRow(rows[i])` just do one call type `sheet.setValues(header + rows[i])`.

**In general, I see 2 options to optimize your script:**

**1.** GAS allows you to run 30 simultaneous executions, so you can adapt your script to run multiple executions, where each execution works a specific range of rows, this way instead of having a 20 min execution to process 100 rows, you have 10 simultaneous executions processing 10 rows and lasting only 2 min.

**2.** All your sheets have the same values, the only difference is their name and the row they reference data, so why not get the data with formula and only use the script to change the names of the sheets?